# org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception

Tags: hibernate

I have an API with weblayer(Controller), application layer and Service layer.
Transaction start in application layer @Transactional(readOnly = false).
When invoked the API it adds a row(propagation =REQUIRES_NEW) in DB and at the end of execution it update(propagation =REQUIRES_NEW) the same entry.
While updating am getting an persistence error(intentional) which am catching and converting as a response.
After debugging I saw the response is forming properly in the service layer and sent back to application layer.
But While returning the response from service to web layer it is throwing "org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException". kindly let me know in case of any further inputs needed.

NOTE: Application doesn't have any implementation except "@Transactional(readOnly = false)" annotaion, am just returning the response form service layer to web layer through application layer.

Comment: Do you mean persistence error as in `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`? Are you catching `PersistenceException` inside the original `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` transaction? If so, try catching it inside the 'update' transaction and re-throwing as a different, checked exception

Comment: @crizzis thank you for the response,
Earlier I was catching PersistenceException and throwing it as hibernate Exception, which didn't work.
As per your suggestion I catched the exception and throwed it as SQLException(Checked Exception) , it is not working. Still can see unexcepted rollBack exception